# SQL: Previous Column empty when setting AVG()

Tags: mysql, sql

Ok, I am a little noobie when it comes to SQL. In fact very muchly so, so I apologize if this is self evident.

I am trying to find out 3 things from database (This table is a log of every message sent):

- Total Reply Time
- Total # of Replies that were Under 10 Mins
- Average Reply Time

Here is my SQL:

```
        SELECT
           *, SUM(case when tmp.reply_time <= 10 then 1 else 0 end) as under_10_mins,
           COUNT(tmp.reply_time) AS total_replies
        FROM
           (SELECT 
              TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, `date`, reply_date) as reply_time
           FROM
               tme_email_staff_reply sr
           JOIN 
               tme_user u 
           ON 
               u.id = sr.staff_id
           JOIN
               tme_email_message m 
           ON           
               m.id = sr.message_id
                   WHERE
               `reply_date` >= '2017-04-01 00:00:00'
           AND 
               `reply_date` < '2017-04-27 00:00:00'
           ) 
        AS tmp
```

Which outputs:

```
    | reply_time | under_10_mins | total_replies |
    |        106 |           165 |           375 |
```

Now, when I add in:

```
        SELECT
           *, SUM(case when tmp.reply_time <= 10 then 1 else 0 end) as under_10_mins,
           COUNT(tmp.reply_time) AS total_replies
        FROM
           (SELECT 
              TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, `date`, reply_date) as reply_time,
              (AVG(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, `date`, reply_date))/60) AS average_reply_time
           FROM
               tme_email_staff_reply sr
           JOIN 
               tme_user u 
           ON 
               u.id = sr.staff_id
           JOIN
               tme_email_message m 
           ON           
               m.id = sr.message_id
                   WHERE
               `reply_date` >= '2017-04-01 00:00:00'
           AND 
               `reply_date` < '2017-04-27 00:00:00'
           ) 
        AS tmp
```

my response is:

```
    | reply_time | average_reply_time |under_10_mins | total_replies |
    |        106 |       149.08626667 |            0 |             1 |
```

As you can see, the **under_10_mins** and **total_replies** fields have changed.

Schema for tables linked:

**tme_email_staff_reply:**

```
    id |    staff_id |   message_id |            reply_date |
     1 | 234,221,001 | 15fg16d5dgw2 |   2017-04-01 09:34:16 |
```

**tme_user**

```
    id |    username |   password |    email |   dob |   gender | 
    // data omited
```

**tme_email_message**

```
   id | thread_id    | From | To | subject | message |  message_id
   // data omited
```

Can anyone tell me why this is so? and how to fix it?

Comment: What's the schema of the tables?

Comment: @SloanThrasher - One sec, will add.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why this is so?

Let's see [`AVG`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_avg):

> **AVG([DISTINCT] expr)**
>
> Returns the average value of expr. The DISTINCT option can be used to return the average of the distinct values of expr.
>
> If there are no matching rows, AVG() returns NULL.

And doc in [**13.19.1 Aggregate (GROUP BY) Function Descriptions**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html) also said:

> If you use a group function in a statement containing no GROUP BY clause, it is equivalent to grouping on all rows. For more information, see [Section 13.19.3, “MySQL Handling of GROUP BY”](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html).

This means in your subquery, you used `avg` without `group by`, this will `avg` all the rows, then return one row in subquery.

How to fix it?

I think you should move `avg` from subquery to outer query:

```
SELECT
   SUM(case when tmp.reply_time <= 10 then 1 else 0 end) as under_10_mins,
   COUNT(tmp.reply_time) AS total_replies,
   AVG(average_reply_time) AS average_reply_time
FROM
   (SELECT 
      TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, `date`, reply_date) as reply_time,
      (TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, `date`, reply_date))/60 AS average_reply_time
   FROM
       tme_email_staff_reply sr
   JOIN 
       tme_user u 
   ON 
       u.id = sr.staff_id
   JOIN
       tme_email_message m 
   ON           
       m.id = sr.message_id
           WHERE
       `reply_date` >= '2017-04-01 00:00:00'
   AND 
       `reply_date` < '2017-04-27 00:00:00'
   ) 
AS tmp
```

Comment: This worked for me. Thank you. Also, Thank you for linking me to something to read. much appreciated.

Comment: Be aware: `reply_time` has no sense on external query, is a random value from `reply_time` nested table.  I posted tou you **The server is free to choose any value from each group.** I down vote until you remove solution proposal or you fix it. srr.

Comment: @danihp I remove `reply_time`, this seems to be useless. And also, your upvote is from me.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is because, in your nested query, you are referring to nonaggregated columns not named in the GROUP BY clause on a MySQL version under 5.7.5. See documentation, notice that: **[The server is free to choose any value from each group](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-handling.html)**.

[MySQL < 5.7.5](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-handling.html) allow this syntax but has special behaviour (your case):

> MySQL extends the standard SQL use of GROUP BY so that the select list can refer to nonaggregated columns not named in the GROUP BY clause. You can use this feature to **get better performance** by avoiding unnecessary column sorting and grouping. However, this is useful primarily when all values in each nonaggregated column not named in the GROUP BY are the same for each group. The server is free to choose any value from each group, so unless they are the same, the values chosen are indeterminate. Furthermore, the selection of values from each group cannot be influenced by adding an ORDER BY clause. Result set sorting occurs after values have been chosen, and ORDER BY does not affect which values within each group the server chooses.

[MySQL >= 5.7.5](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html) allow this syntax and checks for functional dependence:

> MySQL 5.7.5 and up implements detection of functional dependence. If the ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY SQL mode is enabled (which it is by default), MySQL rejects queries for which the select list, HAVING condition, or ORDER BY list refer to nonaggregated columns that are neither named in the GROUP BY clause nor are functionally dependent on them.

Comment: Please could i trouble you for a laymen explanation of this? I'm struggling as I haven't used GROUP BY.... :/